# Easier way to connect to Bluetooth device

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 18.04 which is paired with an external Bluetooth speaker. It takes me seven mouse clicks to connect to this speaker (such as when the laptop has been outside range of the speaker).

1. Click upper right corner of screen
2. Click Bluetooth icon
3. Click Bluetooth Settings
4. Click device name
5. Click Connection
6. Click window close
7. Click window close

Is there a way to connect to a USB device in fewer steps than this?

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at a similar question/answer [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=171144).

First, the MAC Address of the Bluetooth device is needed. You can find it by running the following commands:

1. `sudo systemctl start bluetooth`
2. `bluetoothctl` (a new bash prompt "[bluetooth]#" will be visible after running this command)
3. `devices`
4. Look for the MAC Address of your Bluetooth device by searching through the names of the device listed, assuming the device is powered on and visible.

Finally, run the following commands which start the Bluetooth service and passes the commands through the echo program. These two commands are what you need to connect to your bluetooth device over the terminal.

1. `sudo systemctl start bluetooth`
2. `echo -e 'connect YOUR_DEVICE_MAC_ADDRESS \nquit' | bluetoothctl`

This can be put in a bash script and the bash script can be automated to run upon startup.

Comment: Just typing `bluetoothctl` was sufficient to find the MAC address (at least if the device is already connected). And `echo "connect $DEVICE_MAC" | bluetoothctl` was sufficient to establish a connection when not currently connected. So scripting it would work. Running the script on startup is not useful for me. But calling the script from a hotkey should work.

Comment: Though I didn't use this answer exactly the way it was written. It still gave me the information I needed to create a hotkey to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: @kasperd Could you tell which command did you use exactly for the hotkey? I tried the mentioned command but it didn't work for me.

Comment: thanks! I entered `bluetoothctl` then `scan on` then `connect YOUR_DEVICE_MAC_ADDRESS` once it showed up

Answer (score 3):

Created this simple script to toggle the bluetooth device.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# run "bluetoothctl" to find the MAC address of your device.
MAC="AB:AB:AB:CD:CD:CD"

if hcitool con | grep -q "$MAC"
then
    echo -e "disconnect $MAC \nquit" | bluetoothctl
else
    echo -e "connect $MAC \nquit" | bluetoothctl
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the CLI-based solutions in other answers, there is a Gnome extension called [Bluetooth quick connect](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1401/bluetooth-quick-connect/) which streamlines the GUI a lot. It adds a toggle button to the Bluetooth menu for each paired device, which cuts your number of clicks down to three.

[Screenshot of bluetooth-quick-connect extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFOrD.png)

The easiest way to install Gnome extensions is to first install the Gnome extensions manager (`apt install gnome-shell-extensions`) and the Firefox plugin (which will be linked at the top of the extension's webpage). After that, installing any Gnome extension is just a case of clicking the toggle button at the top of the corresponding webpage.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if you are already connected to the bluetooth device, you can just
sudo systemctl start bluetooth

bluetoothctl

you get a screen show the device in this case "Basilisk X Hyperspeed" in blue

I just typed in "trust"

it said changing "Your MAC address" trust succeeded