# Bluetooth connection - Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: bluetooth

Today I install Ubuntu 19.04. Until now, I'm liking of the system. I have problems of audition, and I use hearing aids. Recently I buy an appliance called Smart connect. This appliance serves to do connect with cellphone and notebook. He is an intermediary of connection. And I saw that  Ubuntu 16.04 and 19.04 don't do connection with this appliance.

So, as Canonical is always improving the system, I want to report a problem so you can work on improving it. Because, other users can be have some problem like my.
The system is easy to use. So, I think it's something for you to think too.

I don't have sure if this is the correct place for this question.

Comment: Do other devices connect to BT?

Comment: Well, on my cell phone, he recognizes. Get connection, send and receive files. But Smart connect does not recognize. Windows only. I only use it at work.

Answer (score 0):

You could file a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu and request support for the new device.  This is not a site for such requests.
For general bluetoth help see   https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/bluetooth-connect-device.html.en
and take a look at [Easier way to connect to Bluetooth device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112259/easier-way-to-connect-to-bluetooth-device)

Comment: Thank's a lot !

I will send !!